# Are $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $ \mathbb{Z}$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

Are  $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $ \mathbb{Z}$    isomorphic ?

My attempt : I think  No because $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$  is not cyclic   but $ \mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic

**Edit** :  Suppose   there  is an isomorphism  $f : \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z_2} \to \mathbb{Z} $.Then $\ker f =\{f \in\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_2  :  f(0,0)=0 \}$

This   implies  that there  exist an  element  $f(0,1)  \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that  $f(0,1)^2=f(0,1) + f(0,1)=f(0+0,1+1)=f(0,2)=f(0,0)=0$

i,e there  exist an   an element   of  order $2$  in $\mathbb{Z}$

This leads to contradiction  because  if  we  take the  $f(0,1)=k \in \mathbb{Z} $ then $f(0,1)^2=k +k=2k =0$  .This implies $(0,1) \in \ker f$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Probably a simpler argument: one of them has an element of order $2$, the other one doesn't.

Comment: You have already received an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4224498/is-mathbbz-2-times-mathbbz-is-cyclic-true-false?rq=1). So you already know that $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z_2$ is not cyclic, but $\Bbb Z$ is. So they cannot be isomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is a good start. Now, prove that $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z_2$ is not cyclic. It should be relatively simple.

Alternatively, you could also:

- note that one of the two groups has a finite subgroup, and the other one does not.
- Note that specifically, $\mathbb Z_2$ is a subgroup of one of the groups and not the other
- Note that all nonzero elements of $\mathbb Z$ have infinite order, while $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z_2$ has an element of finite order. This argument can actually also be used to prove that $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z_2$ is not cyclic.

All of these are (*somewhat related*) arguments showing that the two groups are not isomorphic.